# How to create custom image for UIButton using code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, drawrect

I want to use custom code to draw the image for UIButton.  How do I go about doing that? I have the code that can go into drawRect, but that's for UIView, not UIButton.

In the Custom view's drawRect:

```
@implement MyCustomView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];

   // Vertical stroke
   {
        UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(20, 0)];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(20, 40)];
        [color setStroke];
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
        [bezierPath stroke];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromView {
        [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }
```

In the button code:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
MyCustomView *view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
[button setImage:view.imageFromView forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Matts answer below is good. But it is also very relevant that UIButton inherits from UIView.. So you might create a new subclass of UIButton, override drawRect: with what you have here, swap your buttons out for your new subclass, and avoid images altogether. In other words above you write 'but that's for UIView, not UIButton'. Well a UIButton is a UIView :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use your drawing code to draw into an image graphics context opened with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.
2. Pull out the image using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`.
3. Close the image graphics context with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.
4. Use the image in the button.

Simple example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,100), NO, 0);
UIBezierPath* p =
    [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[p fill];
UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// im is the blue circle image, do something with it here ...
```

Comment: Question - what bounds size should I use for button image?